# How to use specific syntax with C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, models

In Qt/QML  we have this syntax in models:

```
ListModel {
    ListElement {name: 'Willian'; age: 21;}
}

// And we can access the values with this syntax
model.get(x).name // With each key in list
```

But my models are created in Qt using `QStandartItemModel`, and I want access to it as to QML models, however I don't know how to do it. I had thought of operator overloading, but not exists overhead in `operator .` (dot).

I know that we can access `QStandartItemModel` via `data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)`, but QML version is lot more explicit.

Does somebody have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [roleNames](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) method to make some properties visible from QML. It allows you to bind your custom display role (int) to human readable name (visible from QML).

Entire article can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) .